# na.locf with seq in large column in R

Tags: r, data.table, zoo

I'm currently working with a large data.table that has certain groups based on 2 reference columns and then has a column for distance which is defined for the first row in each group and then jumps by 2units each time.

Making a very small reproducible example, I have:

```
reference1 <- c("ref1", "ref1", "ref1", "ref2", "ref2", "ref2", "ref2", "ref3", "ref3", "ref3")
reference2 <- c("fer1", "fer1", "fer1", "fer1", "fer1", "fer1", "fer1", "fer2", "fer2", "fer2")
firstdist <- c(2, NA, NA, 5, NA, NA, NA, 8, NA, NA)
 df <- data.frame(ref1 = reference1,
                  ref2 = reference2,
                  dist = firstdist)
```

which equates to

```
   ref1 ref2 dist
1  ref1 fer1    2
2  ref1 fer1   NA
3  ref1 fer1   NA
4  ref2 fer1    5
5  ref2 fer1   NA
6  ref2 fer1   NA
7  ref2 fer1   NA
8  ref3 fer2    8
9  ref3 fer2   NA
10 ref3 fer2   NA
```

I'd like to fill down the column taking the last observation and carrying it forward +2, so I assume I want to use na.locf from the zoo package for this. Searching around I haven't found any way to carry forward whilst adding a constant integer.

An example of the output I'd like:

```
   ref1 ref2 dist
1  ref1 fer1    2
2  ref1 fer1    4
3  ref1 fer1    6
4  ref2 fer1    5
5  ref2 fer1    7
6  ref2 fer1    9
7  ref2 fer1   11
8  ref3 fer2    8
9  ref3 fer2   10
10 ref3 fer2   12
```

e.g. with something like

```
df$dist <- na.locf(df$dist, by = 2)
```

Not 100% sure na.locf is the best way to do it, so data.table solutions also welcome, but as my table have millions of rows, efficiency is also fairly important

Thank you,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would try the following:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[, dist := seq(first(dist), by = 2, length.out = .N), by = .(ref1, ref2)]

# > df
#     ref1 ref2 dist
#  1: ref1 fer1    2
#  2: ref1 fer1    4
#  3: ref1 fer1    6
#  4: ref2 fer1    5
#  5: ref2 fer1    7
#  6: ref2 fer1    9
#  7: ref2 fer1   11
#  8: ref3 fer2    8
#  9: ref3 fer2   10
# 10: ref3 fer2   12
```

Here, `.N` is the number of rows in each group (grouped by `ref1` and `ref2`).

Comment: Nice option. I was going for `df[, dist2 := dist[1L] + ((seq_len(.N)-1) * 2), by = .(ref1, ref2)]` but yours looks cleaner

Answer (score 1):

Above implementation using dplyr

```
library(dplyr)
df = df %>% group_by(ref1,ref2) %>% 
            mutate(dist = seq(first(dist),by = 2, length.out = n()))
```

Answer (score 1):

A `base R` option would be with `ave`

```
df$dist <- with(df, ave(dist, ref1, ref2, FUN = function(x) x[1] + (seq_along(x)-1)*2))
df$dist
#[1]  2  4  6  5  7  9 11  8 10 12
```

Answer (score 0):

A little bit slower despite not requiring grouping, but this also works:

```
df$dist = Reduce(function(a, b) if (is.na(b)) a + 2 else b, df$dist, accumulate=TRUE)
```